# Avoid Tombstone Event in Debezium - Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, debezium

Im using Confluent Kafka and Debezium Postgres Connector in Confluent Control Center to CDC to a Kafka Topic. I see that on delete event Debezium creates two records in the topic.

1. One with Key and Value as  null
2. Second with "before" state filled in

I would like to avoid Debezium from writing the First record with Key filled and value as null .

I tried setting following property in the Connector :

```
tombstones.on.delete=false
```

But this doesnt seen to have any effect.

Comment: Have you restarted your connector after making this change?

Comment: I created the connecter with this config from confluent control center

Comment: Could you please share the full connector config?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same settings but I run kafka connect in local.

I solved it by using ‘ TombstoneHandler’: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/tombstonehandler.html

Comment: I had the same issue and this solved it.